# Can stress be detected by an fMRI?

Tags: neuroscience, well-being, stress, brain-injury

How does stress damage the brain (if at all)? Is it akin to taking drugs, heavy drinking, or a minor stroke?

Would an fMRI of a stressed person present evidence of stress?

Comment: good question, are you referring to day to day stress, or extreme cases, such as from combat?  Or both?

Comment: @Damien: I was thinking about day-to-day stress, but any related information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There is little evidence that stress affects structural MRI (reduction in the volume of the [hippocampus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocampus)). The review article (*Effects of stress throughout the lifespan on the brain, behaviour and cognition* [Lupien et al., 2009](https://sciencegallery.com/memory/files/papers/Lupien_et_al_2009.pdf)) synthesizes the current knowledge in the field. Another article might be of interest ([MRI measurement of hippocampal volume in post-traumatic stress disorder: A meta-analysis](http://userwww.service.emory.edu/~jdbremn/papers/metaanalysis.pdf)).

If you are interested in functional MRI and day-to-day stress, even less is known. The study  ([Perfusion functional MRI reveals cerebral blood flow pattern under psychological stress](http://www.pnas.org/content/102/49/17804.long)) shows that ventral RPFC (right prefrontal cortex) activation is specifically associated with psychological stress, and this activity persists even beyond the stress-task period.